# Error while Loading CMU sphinx in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am trying to load CMU sphinx in visual studio 2013 but getting some error.
The steps which i followed was

I downloaded sphinxbase-5prealpha and pocketsphinx-5prealpha and extracted to same folder.

Then i complied all the projects from both pocketsphinx and sphinxbase in visual studio(it asked me to upgrade the compliers so i did the upgrade)

now after cleaning the project, when i am trying to build all the project it is throwing a error that 'cannot open sphinxbase.lib' which it is showing in pocketsphinx project.

when i checked the 'sphinxbase.lib' file was already there in the linker of the project.

[image]

According to [this](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx) document the 'sphinxbase.dll' file should be added to the bin files, but it is already added in the directory bot release and debug.

[image]

Similarly it is present in debug directory also.

Please help me, can anybody tell me what wrong i am doing here??

I am just a beginner only in this area.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You extracted files incorrectly. The layout must be the following:

```
root folder
   \____pocketsphinx
      \____ all files like README, src
   \____sphinxbase
      \____ all files like README, src
```

You need to download sources and unpack them into two folders - pocketsphinx and sphinxbase. Then open sphinxbase solution and compile everything. Then open pocketsphinx solution and compile everything. Please note that if you downloaded pocketsphinx-5prealpha you need to rename it to just pocketsphinx. Same for sphinxbase.

Please also note that pocketsphinx_5prealpha_win32 is a binary distribution, you can not compile it. Instead, you can include it directly into your projects.

Comment: Thanks alot Nikolay Shmyrev i am now successfully able to complie them and i have also linked the sphinx in visual studio, now i am trying to use opencv and cmusphinx on raspberry pi2 with windows installed on it. Can you please give me some links or tutorials how to go about it? Thanks !!

Comment: You can learn a lot from this tutorial https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx

Comment: well thanks for quick reply, this link contains a lot details about libraries.. can you share something about opencv and cmusphinx on Raspberry pi2.

Comment: opencv and cmusphinx are also libraries